# Getting at a Core Data object's sub-object's properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios

I have a *Core Data* object called Workshop. It has a to-many relationship to Student objects.

How would I get an `NSArray` of Student surnames (surname being an `NSString` property of Student) from the Workshop object? Preferably in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: Untested Code Incoming

Assuming both your Workshop and Student entities have a "name" attribute and your student entity has a relationship called "Workshop" this is how  you would fetch the objects:

```
- (NSArray*) getStudentsForWorkshop:(NSString*) workshopName {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];   
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Workshop.name LIKE %@", workshopName];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];                                         

    NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [result sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareStudent:)]];
    return sortedArray;      
}
```

For sorting you would implement `compareStudent` like so:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareStudent:(NSManagedObject*)otherObject {
    return [self.name compare:otherObject];
}
```